# Spring Security Refresh Error in Grails jQuery Mobile app

Tags: grails, jquery-mobile, spring-security

I have a Grails 2.0.1 jQuery Mobile app and it's my first use of Spring Security. I followed the excellent instructions in Peter Ledbrook's [post](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/).

After successful login, use of the app and security controls are working fine. However, if a user does a browser refresh an AuthenticationServiceException occurs.

The URL shown in the browser after login is the root of my app plus /j_spring_security_check

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/j_spring_security_check
```

Why is this appended to my URL?  If I manually edit the URL and point to the app's root, there is no problem doing a browser reload.

Comment: I would recommend cranking up the logging on org.springframework.security ... let me know what it says

Comment: Nothing stands out with debug level logging on. Here's one warning that I'm looking into but it doesn't look like it's related: ApplicationContext not found in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.APPLICATION_CONTEXT attribute of servlet context

Comment: that is normal btw .. what is the error that you get when not able to login?

Answer (score 5):

Try setting `data-ajax='false'` to form element

```
<form id="loginForm" name='f' action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />"
                method='POST'  data-ajax="false">
```

Comment: This worked for me! I am so thankful for this. I worked days trying to figure out why this wasn't working. I have to add it to my other pages with <form> postings too.

Answer (score 1):

Great answer. Note that applying data-ajax='false' also applies to the jQuery Mobile "signout" or "logout" button when working with Spring Security. To wit:

```
<a href="j_spring_security_logout" data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="fade" class="ui-btn-left" data-ajax="false">Sign Out</a>
```