# Grails/JQuery mobile view not displayed after login

Tags: jquery-mobile, grails, grails-2.0

Using Grails 2.4.3 and Spring Security plugin `:spring-security-core:2.0-RC4`

The default login view `auth.gsp` is working fine.
Added a user and can login, logout
and view secured pages.

Then I added JQuery mobile files to my layout and view.

I copied auth.gsp to `/views/login/auth.gsp`  [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/H4g75NnS)
My `/views/layouts/main.gsp` layout looks like this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/2FtDMw36)

My login page looks like this:

[image]

When I login with invalid credentials I get a blank page.

[image]

The source of the page before and after submit is exactly the same. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/R4wg5Qje)

If I remove `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>`
from `main.gsp` then I do see the output after submit.

[image]

Hope someone knows what I'm doing wrong.

**UPDATE**
In `plugin/springsecurity/LoginController.groovy`  there is

```
        def authfail() {

            // ....

            if (springSecurityService.isAjax(request)) {
                    render([error: msg] as JSON)
            }
            else {
                    flash.message = msg
                    redirect action: 'auth', params: params
            }
    }
```

If I change this to:

```
        def authfail() {
            // ...

            flash.message = msg
            redirect action: 'auth', params: params               
    }
```

then it is working and I see the login view again.

What still does not work is the redirection after successful login. Stil see a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the answer on [Spring Security Refresh Error in Grails jQuery Mobile app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403584/spring-security-refresh-error-in-grails-jquery-mobile-app) solves mine as well

Need to add `data-ajax="false"` and then it works.